# Using a Windows virtual machine as my everyday computer: feasible in 2020, or too slow?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

For years, I've been dreaming of using a VM as my primary Windows machine as I cringe at having to set up a new machine from scratch every three to five years.

Until now I've been dissuaded by the huge performance degradation implied by a VM, but I'm wondering if in 2020, on high-end hardware, this idea could start to make sense.

For some old 16-bit applications I'm using Windows 2000 on Windows 10 and that works seamlessly, but I'm a bit shy about attempting to virtualize Win7 or Win10 on Windows 10, especially when considering CPU-intensive applications such as Photoshop or watching videos.

Insights please?

Comment: I have several Virtual Machines running on VMware Workstation V15.5.5 on a Windows 10 Pro V2004 Host Machine. The host is a Intel i7 CPU with 16 GB of memory and a very fast NVMe 1 TB SSD. The guest machines work just fine in this environment. I am not discouraged at setting up a new machine every 5 years. I have two working machines and so setting up a new one is fairly easy: Basic updates and main software in one day and remaining software as I go. All software is in my document files.

Comment: You're overthinking this. When upgrading, just keep the disk from old computer or clone it to a new one. Cloning will take as much time as copying the VM virtual disk would. Just make sure to buy BOX license of Windows so changing hardware isn't an issue.

Comment: VMWare which is the elephant in the hypervisor world, won't support DX11, until the next version of Workstation.  So if you need DX 11 or DX 12 it's not realistic to use a virtual machine.  I have no idea when ESXi will support it, but Photoshop, might not support the GPUs that ESXi supports for hardware acceleration.

Comment: Some virtualization software have additional problems with audio devices. For example VirtualBox is nearly useless if you are trying to record audio (e.g. microphone) from my tests. Same is true for forwarding USB Bluetooth devices into the VM: Therefore all type of VoIP or video meeting software are next to useless inside a Virtualbox VM. May be VMWare works better but I don't have a VMWare VM to compare.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a valid Windows license for each VM install? Or is that OT for here?

Comment: @Robert thank you, these are strong arguments in favor of a _no_ in response to my question. If you throw a few sentences into a "No" answer collecting some of the issues of virtualization, I will accept it.

Comment: @zx81 Your question was generic about a virtualized computers, not about Virtualbox. As my comment is only about VirtualBox I don't think it is a fully sufficient answer.

Comment: Everything works perfectly until GPU is required. So, if you will run CPU/RAM intensive application, virtualization works perfectly. For 3d (like Photoshop) you need passthrough the GPU